# how get specific number of data with queryset in python

Tags: python

hi i want to get last specific number of data from database in python
for example i get last three name of my database 
i try

```
last = mpost.objects.count(3)
```

but it gives me error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "example.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: count() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

can you tell me the query that i must write 
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing a wrong query, and using a wrong operator. If you want to get last 3 of a kind, you should use the slices in Python:

```
last = mpost.objects.all()[-3:]
```

Executing the

```
last = mpost.objects.count(3)
```

will try to count object, not to select ones.